# How can you execute multiple calls on a conditional ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a conditional ng-click through which i would like to call multiple methods:

```
<a ng-click="!flag || (setFirst(section); setSecond(section);)">
```

Unfortunately this will not work. But is there a way in which i can wrap these 2 calls together ?

I know that the following approach will work, but i don't to do the check for every single method i'll call

```
<a ng-click="!flag || setFirst(section); !flag || setSecond(section);">
```

The sample code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLtur9tj/1/

Thanks

Comment: Can't you create a function in your controller and do your logic (if, calls, ...) in there?

Comment: No, i don't want to do that. I would like to find a way to wrap those methods in the ng-click

Comment: you're trying to make the simple thing to be complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your methods dont return anything:

```
flag || (func_1() || func_2())
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a ng-click="!flag || (setFirst(section) || setSecond(section))">
```

---

But I recommend not using such logic in your template. You really should consider putting it in your controller, e.g.:

**HTML:**

```
<a ng-click="setSections(flag)">
```

**Controller:**

```
var setSections = function(flag) {
    if(!flag) {
        setFirst(section);
        setSecond(section);
    }
}
```